# How is batch processing done in Hazelcast?

Tags: batch-processing, in-memory-database, hazelcast

I am just a beginner in Hazelcast. I am still learning the basics of it. How is batch processing being done in Hazelcast? Is there any related architecture for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See hazelcast ExecutorService component:
http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.5/manual/single_html/#ExecutorService